# I want to remove " ' " from my string in php. if i m using str_replace() then it removes whole string inside field data

Tags: php, string

i have query like this

```
UPDATE stylesite 
SET  fonts= ''Comic Sans MS', cursive', fontcolor = 'FFB5F8', date = '01-08-2014' 
WHERE stylesite_id = '7'
```

when i m using `str_replace ("'"," ", fonts)`
then it blanks the fonts field.

plz give me other solution

Answer (score 2):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function
www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to Use mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated.